# return array of object javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, methods

With this array:

```
var booksStudents = [
  {
   name: "David", 
   books: {
      "fantasy": 23,
      "action": 31,
      "thriller" 21,
      }
   },
   name: "Paul", 
   books: {
      "fantasy": 17,
      "action": 13,
      "thriller" 23,
      }
   },
   name: "Zoe", 
   books: {
      "fantasy": 5,
      "action": 7,
      "thriller" 28,
      }
}];
```

I would like to return an array of objects, each containing the name of a person and the sum of all their respective books.
I know how to use the reduce method on a simple array but I am stuck with this array of object. 
I was thinking of using `.map` and `.reduce` but I did not find something interesting.

Comment: Implement it with a good old loop first. Then extract the loop body into a function. Then replace a loop with an `Array.prototype.map`

Comment: Your objects seem to miss a few opening braces.

Comment: There are many iterators that you *could* use, such as *map*, *forEach*, *reduce*, *reduceRight*, etc. but the most semantic is *map*. It will create a new array, fill it will whatever your callback function returns, and return it. See [*MDN: Array.prototype.map*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), have a go and post if you have issues.

Comment: @RobG they are not "iterators"

Comment: @zerkms—ok, loopers? ;-)

Comment: @RobG that's a good question :-) I personally would not give them any special name at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
booksStudents = booksStudents.map(function(item){
  var count = 0;
  for(var key in item.books){
    count+=item.books[key];
  }
  item.count = count;
  return item;
})
```

use map and for..in to count the number.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly there are few mistakes in your array of objects, Let me point them.

```
  var booksStudents = [
  {
   name: "David", 
   books: {
      "fantasy": 23,
      "action": 31,
      "thriller": 21,  // : missing
      }
   },
   {                   // { missing
   name: "Paul", 
   books: {
      "fantasy": 17,
      "action": 13,
      "thriller": 23, // : missing
      }
   },
   {                  // { missing
   name: "Zoe", 
   books: {
      "fantasy": 5,
      "action": 7,
      "thriller": 28, // : missing
      }
}];
```

So now after this is fixed the solution to get your end result is by using this code.

```
var newArray = [];
$.each(booksStudents,function(index,value){
    var currObj = {};
    currObj.name= this.name;
    currObj.totalBooks = parseInt(this.books.fantasy) +parseInt(this.books.action)+parseInt(this.books.thriller) ;
   newArray.push(currObj);
});

console.log(newArray);
```

Here is a [Wroking Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/9Lz95km0/) check console for output

The output is as below .

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I do not want to be annoying but I struggled a lot by using the .reduce method. Was it possible or I was in a dead end?

Comment: I don't see a jQuery tag, so it is certainly unwanted since there is the built–in *Array.prototype.forEach*, also the jQuery *each* has the arguments passed to the callback in a different order.

Comment: @sylvain—you can use reduce like: `data.reduce(function(acc, curr) {/* do stuff, push new object onto acc*/;return acc;}, [])`, but *map* is the better choice (more semantic, simpler logic).

Comment: @RobG: Thanks. I was stubborn with the reduce method.

Comment: @Sylvain so you say that your accepted answer works fine for you ?? with the broken object you have??